# How to let the bash shell output font with color?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I meet some command output problems, using 'phpunit' command for example.

I run the phpunit command directly in my linux term, and there are some output with some red/green font color.

```
$>> phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php tests/ExampleTestCase.php
```

But when I put this command to a bash file(test.sh):

```
------------test.sh-------------
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php $file
-------------------------------

$>> chmod u+x test.sh
$>> ./test.sh
```

the output font color is gone. how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

Replace

```
#!/bin/bash
```

by

```
#!/bin/bash -l
```

Comment: Why not `-i` for interactive? There's no reason (and not advisable, I believe) to use a login shell for scripts.